# Singleton Created, Errors upon use in ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've defined NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore as 'CloudStore' in one ViewController (PointsViewController.m), and created a CloudStore singleton in order to be able to use it in another ViewController (PayViewController.m).

However, when I call the Singleton in PayViewController.m, it then throws an error on every NSString reference under it. The error reads: "No known class method forStringForKey" and "No known method for setString:forKey". Am I missing something here? Have I implemented the singleton incorrectly? See ViewController & Singleton code below.

**PointsViewController.m**

```
 NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *CloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];

               NSString *pointsStr = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
               [CloudStore setString:pointsStr forKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
               [CloudStore synchronize];


                NSString *TotalUserPoints = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];


                int pointsInt = [pointsStr intValue];
                int TotalUserPointsInt = [TotalUserPoints intValue];


                TotalUserPointsInt = TotalUserPointsInt + pointsInt;

                NSString *totalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", TotalUserPointsInt];

                [CloudStore setObject:totalStr forKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];
                [CloudStore synchronize];
```

**PayViewController.m**

```
[CloudStore singleton];

        NSString *pointsStr = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
        [CloudStore setString:pointsStr forKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
        [cloudStore synchronize];


        NSString *TotalUserPoints = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];


        int pointsInt = [pointsStr intValue];
        int TotalUserPointsInt = [TotalUserPoints intValue];


        TotalUserPointsInt = TotalUserPointsInt + pointsInt;

        NSString *totalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", TotalUserPointsInt];

        [CloudStore setObject:totalStr forKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];
        [CloudStore synchronize];
       NSString *pointsStr = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
       [CloudStore setString:pointsStr forKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
       [CloudStore synchronize];


        NSString *TotalUserPoints = [CloudStore stringForKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];


        int pointsInt = [pointsStr intValue];
        int TotalUserPointsInt = [TotalUserPoints intValue];


        TotalUserPointsInt = TotalUserPointsInt + pointsInt;

        NSString *totalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", TotalUserPointsInt];

        [CloudStore setObject:totalStr forKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];
        [CloudStore synchronize];
```

**CloudStore.h (singleton)**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CloudStore : NSObject

+(CloudStore *)singleton;

@end
```

**CloudStore.m (singleton)**

```
#import "CloudStore.h"

@implementation CloudStore

+(CloudStore *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static CloudStore *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[CloudStore alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

@end
```

Comment: @Mr.T Hilarious as that is (haha, oops) - it still doesn't fix my errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually messing up the singleton and iCloud storage objects in your code. You need to declare and initialise the iCloud object in your singleton and use it:

**CloudStore.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CloudStore : NSObject

// Storage property
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *cloud;

+ (CloudStore *)sharedStorage;

@end
```

**CloudStore.m**

```
#import "CloudStore.h"

@implementation CloudStore

+ (CloudStore *)sharedStorage
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static CloudStore *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[CloudStore alloc] init];
        [shared initStorage];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (void)initStorage
{
   cloud = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
}
@end
```

And wherever you want to use the CloudStore variable use it like:

Setting data:

```
[[[CloudStore sharedStorage] cloud] setObject:totalStr forKey:@"TotalUserPoints"];
```

Getting data:

```
 NSString *pointsStr = [[[CloudStore sharedStorage] cloud] stringForKey:@"UserWantsToBuyPoints"];
```

Synchronising:

```
[[[CloudStore sharedStorage] cloud] synchronize];
```

You should read this nice tutorial : [iOS Design Patterns](http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1), it'll help you to understand the usage of singleton much better.

Comment: Implemented your above! This line [[[CloudStore sharedStorage] cloud] setObject:totalStr forKey:@"TotalUserPoints"]; in my viewcontroller  throws me the error: "No known class method for sharedStorage"? Also, so I don't need the line [CloudStore singleton]; in the ViewController?

Comment: @Brittany: Please check my full code, I've renamed `singleton` to `sharedStorage` for better readability

Comment: @Brittany: Also please read that linked tutorial whenever you get time, it'll help you to understand the Singleton usage in a much better way :)

Comment: I changed singleton to sharedStorage (as you did above), and I'm still getting the no known sharedStorage class method error O_O

Comment: E.g. so when I use the singleton in my viewcontroller I should put [CloudStore sharedStorage]; in place where this line (NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *cloudStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];) used to be, yes?

Comment: Did you import the header file? On which line you are getting the error?

Comment: header file imported - I get the error (the no stringForKey method and the no sharedStorage note) on just about every line in my ViewController that contains the line "CloudStore" :/

Comment: Are you setting and getting data as mentioned in my answer? You only need to change the keys and value in the above code.